# Get window title on new window

Tags: c++

I'm writing a keylogger type application, and I have pretty much everything done, my problem is getting the window title, I don't want to write the window title every time they press a key, I can get the window title, like I know how to, but how would I only write it to the log when its a new window?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal so is unix by design. That's why we assume it's on Windows.

Comment: @JosephH: Best to ask for clarification, so that (a) you know what you're talking about when you answer, and (b) the OP is trained to be more precise in asking questions.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I totally agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the previous window title and if the current window title is different than the previous window title, print the new window title and set the previous window title to the current window title.

This fails if there's multiple windows with the same name, but it may work for your needs.

Comment: well, if the window title changes as they are typing, I would like the new title

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain an internal list of all windows (with window handles as identifiers to keep memory usage low), and when a new one appears, then you can extract it.

The Win32 API (which I assume you're using) has the function:

```
EnumChildWindows
```

which can be used for this task. Call

```
GetDesktopWindow
```

to supply as the input window handle, and you'll get every window created under this desktop session.

I'm not sure if this would still work via RDP (and Windows Vista+ have the secure desktop as well as the normal clients), but it depends how vital this functionality is for you.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime a keypress is detected, call `GetForegroundWindow` to get the handle to the currently focused window. Store this value as a variable in your program and when it changes, call `GetWindowText` to get the title of the window and log this title.